# The method update(Integer, Integer) is ambiguous for the type CircularLinkedList<Integer>

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, circular-list

i am trying to update an element of node, by searching the old element and replace it with the new one. But there is an error that i dont understand. What leads my code to give that error and how do i fix it ? Error;

```
The method update(Integer, Integer) is ambiguous for the type CircularLinkedList<Integer>
```

`

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CircularLinkedList<Integer> ccl = new CircularLinkedList<>();
    ccl.append(10);
    ccl.append(20);
    ccl.append(30);
    ccl.append(40);
    ccl.append(50);
    ccl.append(71);
    ccl.update(20, 25);

    System.out.println(ccl);
    
    }

}
```

Here is the related method;

```
public void update(E oldElement, E newElement) {
    Node<E> temp = head;
    while (temp.getElement() != oldElement) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.setElement(newElement);
}
```

And here is the all class for better understanding;

```
public class CircularLinkedList<E> {

private static class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
        element = e;
        next = n;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(E e) {
        element = e;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        next = n;
    }
}

private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> tail;
private int size;

public CircularLinkedList() {
};

public void addToHead(E e) {
    Node<E> newHead = new Node<E>(e, head);
    head = newHead;
    tail.setNext(newHead);
    size++;
}

public void append(E e) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node<E>(e, null);
        tail = head;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    Node<E> temp = head;
    while (temp != tail) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e, null);
    temp.next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    tail.setNext(head);
    size++;
    return;
}

public void append(E e, int index) {
    if (index % size == 0) {
        addToHead(e);
    }
    if (index % size == 1) {
        append(e);
    }
    Node<E> temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < (index - 1) % size; i++) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    Node<E> newNodesNext = temp.next;
    temp.setNext(new Node<E>(e, newNodesNext));
    size++;
}

public void update(E oldElement, E newElement) {
    Node<E> temp = head;
    while (temp.getElement() != oldElement) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.setElement(newElement);
}

public void update(E e, int index) {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can not update anything in a empty list.");
    }
    Node<E> temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < (index - 1) % size; i++) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.setElement(e);
}

public void remove(E e) {
    Node<E> temp = head;
    while (temp.next.getElement() != e) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    Node<E> nodeToBeRemoved = temp.next;
    temp.setNext(temp.next.next);
    nodeToBeRemoved.setNext(null);
    size--;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Node<E> temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sb.append(temp.getElement()).append(", ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have two methods called `update`. One is `update(E oldElement, E newElement)` the other is `update(E e, int index)`.

In the case of `E` being of type `Integer`, both method signatures match. `update(E oldElement, E newElement)` is seen as a potential match here, because the primitive `25` in `ccl.update(20, 25);` can be [auto-boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to `Integer`. (The `20` is auto-boxed in both methods)

A solution would be to rename one of your methods. For example `update(E e, int index)` to `updateAtIndex(E e, int index)`.

You can also explicitly cast the first argument to `Integer`. That's enough to tell the compiler which method you want: `ccl.update((Integer)20, 25);`, In that case `update(E e, int index)` will be called.

Weirdly enough, casting only the second argument to `Integer` **won't** work and the compiler will still give you the "Ambiguous method call" error. E.g. `ccl.update(20, (Integer)25)` is not enough to tell the compiler which method you want. *I assume in that case it's because the first argument is subject to boxing, so the second argument is still able to be unboxed as well but I can't say for sure.*